# Comparison of two BigDecimal created differently

Tags: java

I want to compare objects that contain a field with BigDecimal

**First method:**

```
double sumItemsDouble = Arrays.asList(TestConstants.PRICES).stream()
                .mapToDouble(s -> Double.parseDouble(s)).sum();
BigDecimal sumItems = new BigDecimal(String.valueOf(sumItemsDouble));
```

**Second method:**

```
BigDecimal sumItems = items.stream().map(Item::getPrice)
        .reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add);
```

**Create Bill:**

```
Bill bill = new Bill();
bill.setTotalAmount(sumItems);
```

**Results from this methods:**

- 800.0
- 800

I want to compare both objects but they are different because the value in this field does not match

```
Assert.assertThat(bill, is(expectedBill));
```

Comment: You can use the compareTo method to check if they are numerically equal: `bigDecimal1.compareTo(bigDecimal2) == 0`

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS But I have to compare whole objects. BigDecimal is just one of the fields

Comment: implement hashcode/equals in the objects

Comment: hashCode would be not trivial - it must remain the same if numerical value is the same

Comment: I think you can set BigDecimal values to the same scale then equals should work as expected

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you implement `equals` and use the proper comparison as mentioned in the comments:

```
class MyClass {
    BigDecimal value;
    // ... other fields

    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (o == this) return true;
        boolean result = (o instance of MyClass); 
        if (result) {
             MyClass other = (MyClass) o);
             result = areOtherFieldsEqual(other);
             result = result && (value.compareTo(other.value) == 0);
        }
        return result;
    }
    // also implement hashCode()
}
```

As a side note,

```
double sumItemsDouble = Arrays.asList(TestConstants.PRICES).stream()
                .mapToDouble(s -> Double.parseDouble(s)).sum();
BigDecimal sumItems = new BigDecimal(String.valueOf(sumItemsDouble));
```

is a very weird way to convert, `double` to `String`, then parsing as `BigDecimal`. Just do `BigDecimal sumItems = new BigDecimal(sumItemsDouble)`. Better yet, do

```
Arrays.asList(PRICES).stream()
                     .map(BigDecimal::new)
                     .reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use setScale method before comparing.

```
   BigDecimal b1 = BigDecimal.valueOf(800.0).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
   BigDecimal b2 = BigDecimal.valueOf(800).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);

   b1.equals(b2);
```

Comment: ```setScale(0,...)``` essentially throws out all the stuff to the right of the decimal point.   For example, if ```BigDecimal b1 = new BigDecimal("800.01")``` and ```BigDecimal b2 = new BigDecimal("800");``` then your code will say they are the same, which I can't imagine is what the OP wants.

Comment: you can use any scale while calling setScale, not only zero